# NHibernate criteria API - how do I add a clause to compare one date to another date minus a value

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I'm trying to build a criteria object using NHibernate that will compare date1 to date2 minus a value. In Sql Server I'd do this:

select * from table where date1 < DateAdd(Day, 2, date2)

Can anyone tell how I would do this in NHibernate?

Cheers

EDIT

I should have specified this earlier, I'd like to find out how do do this using the criteria API.

Also date1 and date2 are columns on the table, so I don't know their value before running the query

Comment: Are you hoping for a solution using the criteria API, HQL, or Nhibernate.Linq?

Comment: Also..is the parameter of interest here the number of days?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I was wanting to use the criteria API

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need to use DateAdd at all..can't you just calculate the date programatically and compare on that? You need to be clear what your params are here, I think...

Comment: Unfortunately no. The problem is that both date values are columns on the database table, so I don't know either value before running the query. I'm not comparing a programmically declared date with a date in the database, they are both in the database.

Comment: I added a Criteria example for you, but it doesn't make much sense to use Criteria for this query.

Comment: Excellent thanks. I'm pleased someone has shown me how to do it, however I agree it's not the ideal solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, exactly the same way :-)

HQL:

```
session.CreateQuery("from Entity where Date1 < DateAdd(Day, 2, Date2)")
```

SQL:

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(@"select * from table
                         where date1 < DateAdd(Day, 2, date2)")
       .AddEntity(typeof(Entity))
```

Criteria:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Entity>()
       .Add(Restrictions.LtProperty(
            Projections.Property("Date1"),
            Projections.SqlFunction(
                        new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Date,
                                                "DateAdd(Day, 2, ?1)"),
                        NHibernateUtil.Date,
                        Projections.Property("Date2"))))
```

In all cases, `.List()` will execute the query and return a list of objects of the specified type.

Answer (score 0):

Given the minimal amount of information, here's my estimate:

```
TimeSpan timespanToSubtract;
var dateToCompare = new DateTime().Subtract(timespanToSubtract);

// using NHibernate.Linq:
var result = Session.Linq<Table>()
                 .Where(t => t.Date1 < dateToCompare)
                 .ToList();

// using HQL
var hql = "from Table t where t.Date1 < :dateToCompare");
var result = Session.CreateQuery(hql)
                 .SetParameter("dateToCompare", dateToCompare)
                 .List<Table>();
```

Comment: This wouldn't work I'm afraid because I don't know either date value before running the query as they're both columns on the table

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you'll likely need to [create a custom dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845884/custom-sql-function-for-nhibernate-dialect) that registers the dateadd function and then [use the SqlFunction projection](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/04/using-sql-functions-in-criteria-restrictions/) to perform the critiera query.