# NHibernate: Convert order by position(:name_lower IN lower(item.Name)) to hql

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sql-order-by

I have this working SQL Query:

```
select *
from table1 t
where t.Name like '%foo%'
order by position('foo' IN lower(t.name));
```

I need to convert this to HQL.
Using this code

```
var hql = string.Format("select item from {0} item where item.Name like :name order by position(:name_lower IN lower(item.Name))", dtoName);
var query = CurrentSession.CreateQuery(hql);
query.SetParameter("name", string.Format("{0}{1}{0}", "%", name));
query.SetParameter("name_lower", name.ToLower());
```

results in a exception when calling CreateQuery:

```
Antlr.Runtime.MismatchedTokenException
```

Without the order by it works fine. Using

```
order by item.Name
```

Also works fine. So it seems the problem is with the position function.
I've been searching all morning for a hql-equivalent but can't find it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You'll likely need to create a custom dialect and register the position function. Details can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845884/custom-sql-function-for-nhibernate-dialect

Answer (score 0):

I've changed from using the **position** function to the **strpos** function, which does the same except it is accepting two parameters and doesn't use the IN keyword:

```
strpos(lower(item.Name), :name_lower)
```

Now my query works as expected.
I'm glad I didn't needed to create a custom dialect ;)

Thanks.